# Open a Grails project using TextMate

Tags: macos, bash, grails, textmate, textmate2

I have created a simple grails application. When i `ls` the folder the following is what i get:

```
Ma-MacBook-Pro:library ma$ ls
application.properties  lib         test
grails-app      scripts         web-app
grailsw         src         wrapper
grailsw.bat     target
```

Now i want to open this project in TextMate so i can edit it. When i type `mate .` it says `-bash: mate: command not found`.

The TextMate version i am using is `TextMate version 2.0-alpha.9501`. My OS is `OS X 10.9`. Can some one tell me how i could open the project in TextMate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a programming question... Anyway, here goes:

1. `mate` is not on your PATH. What does `which mate` return? (I'm guessing nothing...)
2. In Mac OS X graphical *.app applications (like TextMate would be) is opened with the `open` command. Try `open /Applications/TextMate.app/ .`

Comment: Yes you are correct. However, the project `library` won't open as in eclipse with the folder structure etc on TextMate. How can get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install shell support first.

Open the Preferences, click on the tab named "Terminal". There's a little "Install" button.

If it does not work afterwards, your shell is misconfigured and you should add /usr/local/bin to your PATH environment variable.